# Similar polynomial functions in $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Find $3$ distinct polynomials in $(\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z})[X]$ which determine the same functions as $f(x)=x^2-x+1$ for $f:\ \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$.

To do this problem, is it best to find the roots of $f(x)$ and try and create similar polynomials?
Also, we learned in class that from a polynomial $F[X]$, we can create the function $f(x)$. So does this mean that $f(x)$ is of the same form of $F[X]$, or is it different?
I understand that the three different polynomials must have the same output from the $x$ values $0$ through $4$.
Thanks

Comment: **Hint** $\ g(x) = x^5 -x\ $ is the zero function, so $\,f + gh = f\,$ as functions on $\,\Bbb Z_5.\ $

Comment: Though I don't think it is relevant to the question, at the moment it is not clear what you mean by a polynomial $F[X]$ (where are its coefficients from?), and how you create a function $f(x)$ from it. Would you care to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g\in(\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z})[X]$ define the same function on $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ then $f-g$ is the zero function on $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$. That means $f-g$ has $\overline{0}$, $\overline{1}$, $\overline{2}$, $\overline{3}$ and $\overline{4}$ as its roots, so $f-g$ is divisible by
$$(x-\overline{0})(x-\overline{1})(x-\overline{2})(x-\overline{3})(x-\overline{4}).$$
This product can be simplified by expanding it, see also the comment to the question.
Do you see how you can find plenty of polynomials with the same roots as $f$ now?